# Different ways to initialize variables in Java

Tags: java

I came across the code of `guessgame`. There is a code snippet where three player objects are initialized the following way:

```
public class guessgame{
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
    public void startGame() {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The same worked when I declared and initiated it the following way as well.

```
public class GuessGame {
    Player p1 = new Player();
    Player p2 = new Player();
    Player p3 = new Player();
    public void startGame(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a difference between the two? In the first example, why was the three instance variables declared outside the startgame() method, and does it really matter internally?

Comment: The second version initialises the three players on instantiation of the `GuessGame` class, the first initialises them when `startGame()` is run.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode They're declared at the class level in both cases.

Comment: @Phylogenesis sorry, I guess I can't read. Removing.

Comment: 1st : Initialization at method startGame()  while 2nd at class level

Comment: What does Linux have to do with this?

Comment: @nohup, did you mean to say "why were the 3 instance variables initialized outside of the startgame() method…?"  Obviously they are declared outside of the method, but I just wanted to clarify if you question was about the two initialization approaches.

Comment: It can be useful to leave variables unitialialized at class level or initialize them as an empty Object, or something that indicates its unitialialized. This way, you can tell if a method has been executed yet. It really depends on the design of your code though.

Comment: @bn. I had doubts about both initialization approaches and the scope of the variables. I got that clarified. Thank you.

Comment: @nohup The scope is the same on both (class level) but the initialization time is different (as stated by several answers here)

Comment: The second example lacks a closing bracket on the startGame method. It's driving me a little bit crazy.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode OCD kicks in? I did it for you :)

Comment: local varibales vs instance varibales

Comment: @nohup The class looked like a method at first glance. Optical illusions FTW

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the two?

Yes. The code in the first snippet will execute only in the context of `startGame`. If you do not call `startGame`, the objects would remain `null`. Every time you call `startGame`, the old objects, if any, would be discarded, and replaced with new ones.

The second snippet would execute once for each `GuessGame` object when you call any of its constructors. The code would be shared among all constructors.

> In the first example, why was the 3 instance variables declared outside the `startGame()` method

The only way to declare an instance variable is to do it *outside* a method. Variables declared inside a method are *locals*.

Another difference between the first and the second way is that calling instance methods that access players becomes "legal" only after calling `startGame` in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

If you initialize outside the method, then it is executed when the class is instantiated and memory is allocated for them.  If you don't, it just gets a null (or default value for primitives) assigned to them.

If you never call startgame(), then you're delaying allocating it, and perhaps the user never wants to start the game.  This is smart if the players take a lot of memory to build, and you don't want the user to wait for that to happen (memory allocation), and just run methods immediately (that don't use them).

If for some reason you have several methods that need to use the p1, p2, p3 variables, then coordination of who will initialize may be confusing, so you just might bite the bullet and initialize them upfront.  If you know there will be 3 players, why bother the methods with it?  Otherwise you'll have to do something like:

```
if (p1 == null){
    p1 = new Player();
}
```

Comment: The main advantage of initializing in `startGame()` is that you can always start a new game by calling `startGame()` and the players will be re-initialized. This matters if `Player` holds mutable data such as a score.

Comment: however, it's not mutually exclusive.  say I call it restartGame() and initialize the objects again, should work fine too.

Answer (score 3):

In the second method, you simply do both things at the same time - declare and initialize. The difference is, that you need to run `startGame()` method in the first example to initialize them.

Answer (score 3):

On your first example, the objects are instantiated only when you call the method `startGame()`. Before the call to this method, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are equal to `null`.

On your second example, you declare and instantiate them directly. So they are instantiated at the creation of the class.

Answer (score 2):

1st : Initialization at method startGame()

```
guessgame gg = new guessgame() // Here p1 is null
```

2nd : at class level

```
GuessGame GG = new GuessGame() // OK p1 is initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

`p1`, `p2`, `p3` are not local variables, but class fields.

They are available to all class methods after the class instance was constructed.

In the first snippet, the values of the three fields are `null` *until* the method `startGame()` is invoked.

In the second snippet, the fields are initialized during instance construction.